# Scroll up the content to top when clicking on a Listing ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my site, I have header fixed on top and it has 175px height.

In content part if I click on the listing ID it should take me to the category table which is in bottom of the content.

Triggering script works fine. but the problem is, it scrolls the table to top of the page as it will.

But as I have the header fixed on top, I need to fix the table right below the header from top (`top:175px`) after scrolling.

I am using below code:

```
$('.inventry-title-details ul li a').on('click', scrollToProduct);

function scrollToProduct() { //alert('here');
   verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
   element = $('.inventry-tabel');
   offset = element.offset();
   offsetTop = offset.top;
    ('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 2000, 'linear');
}
```

[BUG-explained-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3uMH.png)

Comment: could you possibly provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Scroll to the element's offset minus the height of the header

Comment: So you do `offsetTop - 175`? or even `-200`

Comment: thx for ur reply! wait for a moment. am creating it

Comment: gentlemen! i tried changing like this $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop-175}, 2000, 'linear'); but still it doesnt works, could you please find out where i have done mistake?

Comment: Hi, the @Spokey answer is correct, you do something wrong (any console error? try to log the value of `offsetTop`)... I do a test: http://jsfiddle.net/nyjLee0n/

Comment: Also note that your script has a random `!` at line 6 and is missing `$` at the 2nd last line

Comment: @Spokey yes!! your answer is right and working superbly!! thanks alot!

Comment: @Frogmouth your jsFiddle is so coooool!!  yea, sorted out the issue.  thanks a lot to all for ur time and help !!